# What does "ITMS-90381: Too many symbol files" warning from Apple means?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect

I'm building a `flutter` app and after just a few tweaks on the code, nothing that should have an impact on the build at all, and after sending the binary, I got the following response from **"The App Store Team":**

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "My App Name" 6.0.6 (204). Your delivery was successful, but
>   you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90381: Too many symbol files - These symbols have no
>   corresponding slice in any binary
>   [21445947-8CB3-35A3-BC25-4A6FAAD91DB1.symbols,
>   A91778CC-3C2E-30C1-A2CE-5F782040B143.symbols,
>   47BA46A8-01A3-3535-A857-33608C98DBC9.symbols,
>   3D6354E1-7749-32BE-A709-CA302D514E18.symbols,
>   8CEFAE31-9C58-35CD-A576-B7A6A8CE766A.symbols,
>   052CBDAC-AF89-3D31-BC0D-7EC7F98FF3B0.symbols,
>   0B85F2D3-F38F-332D-8498-FB7F1C0ECF3A.symbols,
>   1F46C45E-2BCB-3EFF-9949-BD53F801E51E.symbols,
>   6C5D68B0-3705-37E8-A6F2-B59887EAFC38.symbols,
>   2D699377-49C0-3E13-886F-955FC8B0825D.symbols,
>   84935D3A-07B4-3979-B919-29571C48901C.symbols,
>   8BB1A3E6-62AA-3AAE-8FA2-78ED428863CB.symbols,
>   2BC5656F-C2A2-3161-8E67-5779B3C9055A.symbols,
>   2E997F4D-497D-3745-9DA6-5773F13D55A7.symbols,
>   C1CCBE3E-E0CB-3A2A-8D69-0E0769875284.symbols,
>   F6BAFC0F-1D98-3C4E-BE8F-1AF4A70F3ED0.symbols,
>   B943F468-8598-386A-BB5F-5B38EB5663F4.symbols,
>   C067AB62-1D03-3A02-ADAE-4C15166C964F.symbols].
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App
>   Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

To be honest, I don't have a clue of what that means. I'm pretty sure it is a `flutter` problem but either way, I'd like to understand better what are those `symbols` they are talking about, what is "too many" and hopefully how to fix it.

It's just a warning, the build passed, but I don't like it. These things tend to pile up and escalate to bigger and weird problems.

Comment: I have this warning as well, and ours is a straight Cocoa app, no Flutter.

Comment: @stevex are you using Firebase on your project? I believe this is coming from their libraries.

Comment: I am, yes - that seems likely.